# How can I optimise runtime in Python - deepcopy problem

Tags: python

I'm running a program with many iterations for a reinforcement learning problem.

Part of this requires me to build a large list as I go, filled with numpy.ndarrays. I originally tried this code to append new nd.arrays to the list as i go:

```
    table.append(array)
```

However I found that this didn't work for my data structure as it replaced the previous value, and I replaced it with

```
    table.append(copy.deepcopy(array))
```

Which i later changed to:

```
    table.append(copy.copy(array))
```

However, the running of my program is extremely slow, and using copy thousands of times I think must be an issue. I'm relatively new to Python but:

Is there a faster way I can go about this, maybe an approach with 'append' that I'm not aware of?

Also, how slow really is using copy/deepcopy instead of append? This part is just out of interest

Thanks for any pointers

Comment: Is table a python list or a numpy array? It will be faster if you use numpy's append `table = numpy.append(table, myNumpyArray)` https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html

Comment: Table is a python list

Comment: See if you can refactor your code to only work with numpy data structures, it will be much faster overall because they're extremely optimized

Comment: Thanks for the pointers

Comment: From what I've read, numpy.append creates a new space in memory to store a whole new array. Is this not as inefficient as 'copy'?

Comment: Check out my answer for some details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres some test code:

```
import numpy as np
import time
from copy import deepcopy, copy

py_list = []
py_list_dc = []
nd_array = np.random.rand(1000000, 100)

start = time.time()
for i in range(9):
    my_array = np.random.rand(1000000, 100)
    nd_array = np.vstack((nd_array, my_array))
end = time.time()
print("Numpy: {}, {} (shape)".format(end - start, nd_array.shape))

start = time.time()
for i in range(10):
    my_array = np.random.rand(1000000, 100)
    py_list.append(copy(my_array))
end = time.time()
print("Py (copy): {}, {} (len)".format(end - start, len(py_list)))

start = time.time()
for i in range(10):
    my_array = np.random.rand(1000000, 100)
    py_list_dc.append(deepcopy(my_array))
end = time.time()
print("Py (deepcopy): {}, {} (len)".format(end - start, len(py_list_dc)))
```

And the output (on my machine, maxed 2017 Macbook Pro):

```
Numpy: 147.2119209766388, (10000000, 100) (shape)
Py (copy): 26.23211121559143, 10 (len)
Py (deepcopy): 30.158884048461914, 10 (len)
```

As you can see from the results using numpy append/vstack/concatenate is slower than copy or deepcopy. The results don't scale linearly as well, they're exponential as you add more rows and columns (try it out on your machine). Here's a few things to try:

- Time other places in your code to see where the bottleneck is (A profiler will be helpful https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/profile.html)
- See if you can Vectorize or use list comprehensions instead any loops you may be using
- See if you can reduce the size of your dataset (minimize the amount of rows/columns you're generating)

Without seeing the full program it's hard to guess where the bottleneck is but those are a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll try some other things